# Is it possible to mount CIFS onto Solaris 10 server

Tags: cifs, solaris-10, smbfs

I want to mount a SAN CIFS share on a solaris 10 u11 server.

I found and info doc from Oracle saying its not supported until Solaris 11.

Are there any 3rd party / Freeware tools for Solaris 10 that will enable the mounting of a CIFS share on Solaris 10 ?

Comment: if mounting cifs on solaris 11 isn't supported, why you think is supported on solaris 10?

Comment: not support UNTIL Solaris 11. ie it is in Solaris 11

Comment: but i had been working with solaris 10 for some year and no cifs was there :)

Comment: You can use NQ server at www.CIFS.com. However it is a commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smbfs/cifs is not supported on Solaris 10.
however, you can use smbclient to access the share from Solaris 10 (this is what we do), with something like :

```
/usr/sfw/bin/smbclient -m SMB2 -W DOMAIN -U USER%PASSWORD //HOST.DOMAIN/Yoursharename
```

you can also pass commands to it, with e.g:

```
/usr/sfw/bin/smbclient -m SMB2 -W DOMAIN -U USER%PASSWORD //HOST.DOMAIN/Yoursharename -c 'cd /folder; dir; exit;'
```

hope that helps
regards,